Sign of $\Re\frac{\xi'(s)}{\xi(s)}$ locally around a zeta zero
In the article ”On a positivity property of the real part of logarithmic derivative of the Riemann $\xi$–function” the authors check the positivity of $\Re \frac{\xi'}{\xi}(s)$ for $\frac{1}{2}<\sigma<1$ assuming that there occur a non-trivial zeros of $\zeta(s)$ off the critical line. Briefly, they study the three possible cases : 1. There is only one zero in the region $\{\sigma+it: \frac{1}{2}<\sigma<1, t>0\}$, 2. There is a finite number $n \geq 2$ of zeros off the critical line, 3. There are infinitely many of zeros off the critical line.
In case 1 and 2 they obtain gray regions (as in the figure) where $\Re \frac{\xi'}{\xi}(s)>0$ and the dots on the curve separating the white and gray region represent zeta zeros.

I'm interested to know about the sign behaviour of $\Re \frac{\xi'}{\xi}(s)$ locally around a possible zeta zero $s_0$ off the critical line. My questions(interested in all three cases): does there exist a small neighbourhood around $s_0$ such that $\Re \frac{\xi'}{\xi}(s)>0$ for all $s$ except $s_0$? If the previous question has no affirmative answer does there exist a smooth curve passing through $s_0$ as in the figure such that in some small disc around $s_0$ we have $\Re \frac{\xi'}{\xi}(s)>0$ in the gray region(intersected with the disc) and $\Re \frac{\xi'}{\xi}(s)<0$ in the white region?

If a complex function $f(s)$ has a zero at $s_0$ of order $n\geq 1$, then for suitable $r>0$,
$$\frac{f'(s)}{f(s)}=\frac{n}{s-s_0}+O(1),\qquad 0<|s-s_0|<r.$$
Writing $s=s_0+\rho e^{it}$ with $\rho\in(0,r)$ and $t\in\mathbb{R}$, the previous display yields that
$$\Re\left(\frac{f'(s)}{f(s)}\right)=\frac{n}{\rho}\cos(t)+O(1)=\frac{n}{\rho}\bigl(\cos(t)+O(\rho)\bigr).$$
So there is a constant $c>0$ (depending on $f$ and $s_0$) such that $\Re(f'(s)/f(s))>0$ for $\cos(t)>c\rho$, and $\Re(f'(s)/f(s))<0$ for $\cos(t)<-c\rho$. Note that the sign of $\cos(t)$ is the same as the sign of $\Re(s-s_0)$.

If I'm not mistaken your corrected answer gives information on the sign of $\Re(f'(s)/f(s))$ only on the horizontal line passing through $s_0$?

@AlexisΣ Yes, but one can say more. See my "Added" section. The point is the we have definite information about the sign of $\Re(f'(s)/f(s))$ unless the vector $s-s_0$ is close to being vertical.

I would be grateful if you could elaborate on your answer. If we now consider $\xi$ and look at the picture of my post and consider the case of a finite number of zeta zeros, then that there exists a zeta zero $s_0=\sigma_0+it$ (the one closest to the line $\sigma=1$) such that $\Re(\frac{\xi'(s)}{\xi(s)})>0$ for $\sigma \geq \sigma_0$(this is a theroem of Sondow-Dumitrescu) . But if we take an "extremely" small disc $D$ around $s_0$ then what kind of shape is $\Re(\frac{\xi'(s)}{\xi(s)})<0, s \in D$?

@AlexisΣ I rewrote my answer with more detail. I hope this helps.
